# Помощь в верстке

Tags: html, css

Всем привет. Хотел спросить как это сделать как на картинке.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Подгрузка страниц `get` запросами

Comment: ajax используйте

Comment: @slippyk, почему ajax?

Comment: Можно сделать фреймами почитать про Frame Frameset iframe

Comment: у меня backend на Ruby on Rails

Comment: @Doofy, а почему не `Post`?

Comment: @MasterAlex, без разницы. При загрузке странички файлы грузятся get запросом, вот и написал

Comment: Специально для этого придумали Angular

Answer (score 1):

Доброго времени суток. Могу предложить как вариант решения вопроса, это использовать библиотеку ExtJs. Но это при условии если достаточно серьезный проект пилить думаете. Если же просто накидать рыбу легкую то усилия будут неоправданны. Вот пример админ панели на ExtJs:
[пример](http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.0/examples/admin-dashboard/#faq)

Почитать про четвертую версию библиотеки можно [тут](http://metanit.com/web/extjs/1.1.php)
в принципе для понятия принципов должно хватить. Ну и не забываем про официальные сайты и примеры)

Comment: Проект такой: есть adelfi.kz. Надо для этого сайта сделать админ панель чтобы изменять 
1) Готовые проекты, динамические папки с названием и фотками 
2) Контактные данные (все поля, даже гео пин)
3) О нас, информативная текст 
4) Команда, ФИО, аватарка, Должность
5) СМИ о нас (текст и ссылка на видео Youtube)
6) Vk/Facebook/Instagram Ссылка в шапке
все надо сделать на Ruby on Rails. еще надо landing page с 0 написать. не знаю с чего начать и не знаю как делать сижу и мучаюсь. Помогите, дайте путь к старту

Comment: Ну в принципе если вам не принципиально постоянное обновление страниц при переходе по ссылкам меню, то можете использовать макет bootstra,p как у вас на примере, только меню формировать в отдельном partial (пишу терминами asp.net т.к. с ruby к сожалению не знаком). а если все же надо через ajax гонять то мой предыдущий вариант в принципе работоспособен. с чего начать на ruby.. вот из-за незнания руби подсказать не смогу:(